# How to attach audio file to MMS in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to attach audio file to MMS.How to do that?I found a lot on SO as well as on Goggle but still not got rhe right solution yet.So someone help me for my this issue.My code is as:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body",
                    getResources().getText(R.string.Message));
            sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms",
                    "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");


            AssetManager mngr = getAssets();
            InputStream path = null;
            try {
                path = mngr.open("*.mp3");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(path, 1024);

            // get the bytes one by one
            int current = 0;
            //
            try {
                while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {

                    baf.append((byte) current);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // /TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] bitmapdata = baf.toByteArray();

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath(), "*.mp3");

            // if (file.exists() == true) {
            // } else {
            // Log.v("directory is created", "new  dir");
            // file.mkdir();
            // }

            FileOutputStream fos;

            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(bitmapdata);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // handle exception
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // handle exception
            }

            final File file1 = new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
                    "*.mp3");
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file1);
```

//              Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/*.mp3");
                Log.e("Path", "" + uri);

```
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

            // sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mms_uri.toString());

            // startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, ""));
            startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Please tell me where i am wrong in above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this snippet in your scenario:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra("text-body", "if you are sending text");    
sendIntent.putExtra("num", "number");

sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("ur file path"));
sendIntent.setType("audio/3gp");
```

Comment: well actually i did the same thing what you are trying to say.Still got the problem.

Comment: I have passed you my code which I am using...if its not working then let me know at which point you are getting problem and pass me the logs too.

Comment: well i am not getting any force close but the only thing is that i am not abble to attach audio file to MMS.I am able to store audio file to SD cArd successfully.

Comment: Read your logs, it must be like you were not passing the correct URI path.

Comment: i am getting correct path in log but still not able to attache it.