# Attached audio file as a mms in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, sms, mms

I am develop one app that require record the voice.and that voice can be automatically attached to the mms.

i am useing this code

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
                sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
                sendIntent.putExtra("address", "9999999999");
                sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "if you are sending text");   
                final File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"connection.amr");
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file1);
                Log.e("Path", "" + uri);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                sendIntent.setType("*/*");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
```

all of the going fine but file can't attached automatically.any idea about this??

When user click on send button that time automatically attached that file in particular number with subject and sms_body part that it.

My file Extension is **.3gp**

**This code is perfect work in Samsung ace 5830i and Samsung Galaxy nexus but not work in Htc desire c,Htc one.**

I am tested this setType.but not positive response.

```
  sendIntent.setType("video/3gp");
  sendIntent.setType("audio/*");
  sendIntent.setType("*/*");
  sendIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
```

**If automatic attachement is possible or not?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to attach audio file to MMS in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028990/how-to-attach-audio-file-to-mms-in-android)

Comment: @MichaelMior right but no one have idea about that.in my question when user click on send button automatic attached mms in particular number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra("text-body", "if you are sending text");    
sendIntent.putExtra("num", "number");

sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("ur file path"));
sendIntent.setType("audio/3gp");
```